# Firefox is linking the tag removal button to the tag

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

I'm running into an issue while trying to re-tag a question.

For some reason, the tag link is including the X in itself.  I try to remove the tag, it gets removed, and then I get sent to the tag page.  I can't retag questions when it does that.

[image]

This is using FireFox 18.0.1, which says it's up to date.

I double-checked Chrome and IE, and they're working correctly.  I also checked Meta.SO, and it's working fine with Firefox there.  As far as I can tell, this just started happening today, on Arqade.

Or is my Firefox just borked?

Comment: If all else fails use the keyboard. That one is a text field, after all.

Comment: No Repro on my end. Using 18.0.1 with no addons / extensions (that includes Java / flash)

Comment: No repro for me at home, either.  Just my work computer doing wonky things.

Comment: I get this issue on chrome 24.0.1312.57 m . The tag disapears then I'm linked to the tag page

Comment: I am actually unable to reproduce the 'on hover' tooltip effect to get to the tag info page, let alone them both combining into one action - 25.0.1364.68 beta-m

Comment: And now, it works fine.  Some design changes happening in the background, I guess?